# How to prove $n*\varphi(n)/2 $ sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

how do I prove The second formula from [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) ?

$$\sum_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\(k,n)=1}} k=\frac 12 n \varphi(n)$$
for $n>1$.

[image: Euler's_totient_function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that there are exactly $\phi(m)$ integers less than $m$ and relatively prime to $m$.
Also if $a<m$ and $(m,a)=1$ then clearly $m-a<m$ and $(m,m-a)=1.$
Thus there are exactly $\phi(m)$ integers $a_{1},a_{2},...,m-a_{2},m-a_{1}$ less than $m$ and relatively prime to $m$.
Let $$S=a_{1}+a_{2}+...+(m-a_{3})+(m-a_{2})+(m-a_{1})$$
Now writing the above term in reverse order, we get,
$$ S=(m-a_{1})+(m-a_{2})+...+a_{2}+a_{1}$$
Adding above two results,
$$2S=m+m+...+m(\phi(m)\text{ terms})$$
$$\therefore S=\frac{m\phi(m)}{2}$$
It implies that the sum of $\phi(m)$ positive integers which are less than $m$ and relatively prime to $m$ is $\frac{m\phi(m)}{2}$.

Comment: I hope my answer useful. @Rami

Answer (score 6):

If $0<k<n$ and $\gcd(k,n)=1$ then $\gcd(n-k,n)=1$ and $k+(n-k)=n$.

Comment: I fail to see how the equality follows from this. I know that $\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, but it seems that for this case, the $n+1$ term is replaced by $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: It is a summation over φ(n)/2 pairs, each of which sum to n.

Comment: I see it now. That makes perfect sense. Thanks. :) And +1 to the OP for this question.